# when i run the script its give me a duplicate output

Tags: php

i'm using this code to grab links from a web page.
the problem is that its duplicate the links i grab .
so plz can anyone tell where is the problem.
thanks in advance.Regards

```
           foreach ($html->find('a') as $element1 )
              {

           $element2 = $html->find('.Title');
           preg_match_all('(videopage[^\"]*)' , $element1, $results1);
                if(!empty($results1[0]))
                      {
                          $result1 = implode("','",$results1[0] );
                          $link = "http://arabic-media.com/";
                          echo   $link.$result1 ."\n";

                       }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure the link won't get matched twice? Or is twice in your HTML document?

Comment: What do you mean with `it duplicates the links i grab`? Does it gets echoed twice? Or is it twice in the variable `$result1`?

Comment: it get's echoed twice

Comment: Could you try running [this code](http://pastebin.com/r2ZqRhPW) so you see if there is an item with both different ids...

Comment: thanks Guys for help ,but i found the problem .i replace the 'a' with     'table td[align=left]'